# WiX localization - Desktop/Program menu short cut not replaced in Upgrade

Tags: windows, localization, wix

We have recently included localization support for simplified Chiense (zh-cn) in Windows Installer using WIX 3.5. The current version of our product is 1.3.0 and in old version (1.2.0) we do not have any localization support.

We have also changed the product code for 1.3.0 in order to perform major upgrade. And used MSI transform (using Wisubstg.vbs and Wilangid.vbs ) to integrate the localization support into single MSI without using Bootstrapper.

When we test this in Simplified Chinese build in upgrade mode the desktop and prpogram menu short cuts were not replaced but duplicated with Chinese text.

WiX Short cut code is here.

```
<Shortcut Id="StartServiceShortcut" Icon="StartServiceIcon" 
     Name="!(loc.STR_StartServiceName)" 
     Description="!(loc.STR_StartServiceDesc)"  
     Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]bin\myapp.exe" Arguments="-s" 
     WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"/>
```

product.Wxl

```
<String Id="STR_StartServiceName">Start Service</String>
<String Id="STR_StartServiceDesc">Start Services</String>
```

- Installed 1.2 build with Windows 7 English version
- Changed the Regional settings to Simplified Chinese and then run the 1.3 Installer.
- Seen the Windows Installer Wizard showiing the contents in simplified Chinese.
- Installation was successful. But Desktop/Program menus are duplicated with new Chinese text.
- Both shorcuts are working with out any issues. But uninstall did not remove both shourt cuts.

Uninstall product does not remove the short cuts.  I have also seen that two entries in the Programs/Features list. Also seen there are two different registry entries. The product name and Publisher values are localized all other properties are same in these to Registry keys.

Where am I missing?

Thanks in Advance for any help!

Update:

After changing the upgrade language to '0', I am still getting the same issue. It seems like this new version 1.3 has been installed as totally a new product. Any help!
        After changing the upgrade language to '0' I am still getting the same issue. It seems like this new version 1.3 has been installed as totally a new product.  Any Help!

```
    <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />


    <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                        IncludeMinimum="no"
                        OnlyDetect="yes"
                        Language="0"
                        Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND" />

        <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.RTMProductVersion)"
                        IncludeMinimum="yes"
                        Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                        IncludeMaximum="no"
                        Language="0"
                        Property="UPGRADEFOUND" />

    </Upgrade>
    <Product Id="$(var.ProductID)" Name="!(loc.STR_ProductName)" Language="!loc.STR_Language)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="!(loc.STR_Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. Thanks to Alex Shevchuk's Blog [From MSI to WiX, Part 8 - Major Upgrade](http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/15/from-msi-to-wix-part-8-major-upgrade.aspx)
.

> The FindRelatedProducts action runs through each record of the Upgrade table in sequence and compares the upgrade code, product version, and language in each row to products installed on the system.

So, After changing my code to something like below, upgrade was successful. Could be useful to others.

Any comments are welcome!

```
  <Product Id="$(var.ProductID)"
  Name="!(loc.STR_ProductName)"
  Language="0"
  Version="$(var.ProductVersion)"
  Manufacturer="!(loc.STR_Manufacturer)"
  UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

<Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" Languages="0" Manufacturer="!(loc.STR_Manufacturer)"  />

<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />


<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                  IncludeMinimum="no"
                  OnlyDetect="yes"
                  Language="0"
                  Property="NEWPRODUCTFOUND" />

  <!-- For UPGRADEFOUND Property, the Language attribute should be set to 1033 as previous version supports only English -->
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.RTMProductVersion)"
                  IncludeMinimum="yes"
                  Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)"
                  IncludeMaximum="no"
                  Language="1033"
                  Property="UPGRADEFOUND"  />

</Upgrade>
```

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so other will see your question has been answered and be able to learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: @ Andrew Kozak   Accepted. Thanks for the comments.